# Spring Data JPA JDBC statements MADNESS

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I have a simple Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dish_type")
class DishType : Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long = -1
    var name: String? = null
    var description: String? = null
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "dishType")
    var dishTypeLocales: List<DishTypeLocale>? = null
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "dish_type_locale")
class DishTypeLocale : Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long = -1

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    var locale: LocaleString? = null
    var value: String? = null

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "dish_type_id")
    var dishType: DishType? = null
}
```

DAO:

```
interface DishTypeService {
    fun findAll(withLocale: Boolean): List<DishTypeDto>
}

@Service
@Transactional
open class DishTypeServiceImpl(private val dishTypeRepository: DishTypeRepository) : DishTypeService {

    override fun findAll(withLocale: Boolean): List<DishTypeDto> {
        return this.dishTypeRepository.findAll().map { DishTypeDto(it, withLocale) }
    }

}

@Repository
interface DishTypeRepository : JpaRepository<DishType, Long>
```

DTO:

```
class DishTypeDto {
    var id: Long = -1
    var description: String? = null
    var locale: List<DefaultLocalizationDto>? = null

    constructor()

    constructor(dishType: DishType, withLocale: Boolean) {
        this.id = dishType.id
        this.description = dishType.description
        if (withLocale) {
            this.locale = dishType.dishTypeLocales?.map { DefaultLocalizationDto(it) }
        }
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "DishTypeDto{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                '}'
    }
}


class DefaultLocalizationDto {
    var locale: Int? = null
    var name: String? = null
    var description: String? = null

    constructor()

    constructor(locale: DishTypeLocale) {
        this.locale = locale.locale?.code
        this.name = locale.value
    }

    override fun toString(): String = "DefaultLocalizationDto(locale=$locale, name=$name, description=$description)"
}
```

In case of `DishTypeService.findAll(false)` we have 1 statements to DB:

```
Session Metrics {
    6789040 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    146499 nanoseconds spent preparing 1 JDBC statements;
    3929488 nanoseconds spent executing 1 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    43774 nanoseconds spent executing 1 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
```

In case of `DishTypeService.findAll(true)` statements == table.size (in my case 282):

```
Session Metrics {
    11570010 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    4531164 nanoseconds spent preparing 282 JDBC statements;
    60280410 nanoseconds spent executing 282 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    60464 nanoseconds spent executing 1 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
```

How to tell Spring, to get all data in 1(ok mb 2-3 statements) ?

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "dishType", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
var dishTypeLocales: List<DishTypeLocale>? = null
```

EAGER didn't help

I know, I can remove `dishTypeLocales` from `DishType` and in 2 separate methods get all `dishTypes` then all `dishTypeLocales`, and then in code map them, but mb there is some better way?

I'm using:

```
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
```

DB: Postgresql 9.6

Comment: Is this the minimal working example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are experiencing lazy loading of relationships which is the default behavior of the `OneToMany` relationships.

You have 4 options here:

1. Set EAGER loading for the relationships (I know you wrote that you've already tried it and it didn't work but trust me, it's working. You were just probably experiencing a different issue)
2. Use `FETCH JOIN` to load the entity along with the relationship. For this you have to write a custom method in your repository with the following query (draft): `SELECT dt FROM DishType dt JOIN FETCH dt.dishTypeLocales`
3. Use Spring Data JPA's feature, [Fetch/LoadGraph](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-graph)
4. Use [projections](http://blog.arnoldgalovics.com/2017/03/14/using-projections-in-your-data-access-layer/) as this is a read-only operation. It's best to avoid using entities when you are reading data and stick with them only when you are modifying data.